# Dual-boot without bootmanager, i.e. to have a default boot OS

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

I'd like to make my (Windows 10) desktop computer into a dual-boot system Windows-Ubuntu. However, since Windows 10 will be the most used operating system by far, I wonder if it's possible to do this in such a way that the computer always automatically boots into Windows, preferably without showing any bootmanager and without a significant decrease in speed compared to the current single-boot situation. Ubuntu would then have to be accessed by a one-time-boot menu, triggered by pressing a button during startup (probably F12 on my system).

Is this possible at all and how should I go about this?

Comment: Although I understand what you want, it is really not a configuration option from within Ubuntu, it depends on your BIOS. Google search on your computer and bios . As an alternate you can try https://www.howtogeek.com/65974/how-to-easily-change-your-dual-booting-pcs-default-os/ and change your grub options .

Comment: Is this a UEFI machine?  If so, simply put the Windows bootloaders before grub in the boot order.

Comment: It is, but I don't remember the option to pick a bootloader, only to pick a the medium to boot from (e.g. hard drive, usb stick, dvd); not helpful when both are installed on the same drive. I'll have access to the system again in a week, will test.

Comment: See comment to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broadly speaking, there are two ways to do this:

- **Configure Windows first in the EFI boot manager** -- After installing Ubuntu, type `sudo efibootmgr`. This will show you a list of boot programs, which should include both `ubuntu` and `Windows boot manager`. Each of those will have an associated number (`Boot####`). There will also be a `BootOrder` line that shows the order in which boot entries are tried. Chances are Ubuntu will be first in the boot order and Windows will be second. You can reverse that order by using the `-o` option to `efibootmgr`. For instance, suppose Ubuntu is `Boot0008`, Windows is `Boot0003`, there are a couple more entries, and the current boot order is `0008,0003,0006,0005`. In this case, you might type `sudo efibootmgr -o 0003,0008,0006,0005` to reverse the Windows and Ubuntu boot orders. You can do the same thing in a GUI way in Windows by using the third-party [EasyUEFI](http://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html) tool. When you're done, Windows will boot by default; and to boot Ubuntu, you'll need to hold whatever key your computer uses to enter its built-in boot manager, which will enable you to select the `ubuntu` entry.
- **Configure Windows first in GRUB (or another user-installed boot manager)** -- Instead of relying on the EFI boot manager, you can leave GRUB as the first boot entry and configure it to boot Windows by default. You can also adjust the timeout and configure GRUB to not display its menu unless you hold (IIRC) the Shift key. Such changes are normally made via an assortment of GRUB configuration files and then running `sudo update-grub`; however, the [GRUB Customizer](https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/ubuntu/grub-customizer) utility helps you to do this in a GUI way. (I'm not much of a GRUB person so I don't know a lot about GRUB Customizer and can't help beyond a pointer to the PPA.) You can do similar things with my own rEFInd or other boot managers, but details differ, and these would require installing extra software, so you're probably best off reconfiguring GRUB for your needs, unless you find that you can't do quite what you want.

Note that what was a boot medium selector in BIOS-based computers has been expanded into a boot manager in most EFI-based computers. Under EFI, there *should be* options to boot particular OSes (or their boot loaders, to be more precise), not just disks. If you don't see such options after installing an OS, then chances are you firmware is defective, or at least very poorly designed. In this case, you may have no choice but to rely on GRUB or some other boot manager to do what you want.

Comment: Tried first option first. Strangely, placing GRUB second in the UEFI boot order made it impossible to boot without the nomodeset parameter, whereas there are no problems when GRUB is first (furthermore, GRUB boots into Windows just fine). Your second solution did the job, although it lengthens the boot process, since now both UEFI and GRUB are waiting for a key to be pressed before proceeding . But thanks for your help anyway!